# LZ_UNCOMPRESS inn. Oracle PL/SQL does not work as expected, unable to uncompress compressed data

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, blob, oracle-autonomous-db

The thing which I want to achieve is using Oracle Pl/sql stored procedure - I want to compress a blob data and put that in a json.

The structure will be like. -
{"Client_id" : "12345", "Blob_data" : compressed_blob_data}

I want to store the above content in a file in object storage in OCI, or we can assume that I am storing the file in local machine as .json file. I have compressed the data using UTL.LZ_COMPRESS and have put the same in compressed_blob_data BLOB variable.

But after extracting the BLOB data from JSON file when I am trying to uncompress the data present for the key "Blob_data" in the JSON file, oracle is throwing error as below-

Error report -
ORA-29294: A data error occurred during compression or uncompression.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SYS_COMPRESS", line 60

ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SYS_COMPRESS", line 230

ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_COMPRESS", line 89

ORA-06512: at line 32 29294. 00000 -  "A data error occurred during compression or uncompression."

*Cause:    An error occurred while compressing or uncompressing input source.

*Action:   Verify that source data is a valid compressed or uncompressed

````
DECLARE
  DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_BLOB                 JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T();
  DATASET_BLOB_DATA_CERNER_MONITORING               BLOB;
  DATASET_BLOB_DATA_CERNER_MONITORING_BASE64_STR    CLOB;
  DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_CLOB                 CLOB;
  CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2(50);
  DATASET_BLOB_DATA BLOB;
  OBJECT_STORAGE_URI_CERNER_MONITORING VARCHAR2(500);
  OCI_CREDENTIAL VARCHAR2(400) := 'OCI$RESOURCE_PRINCIPAL';
  OCI_REGION VARCHAR2(50) := 'us-zzz-1';
  OBJECT_STORAGE_NAMESPACE VARCHAR2(50) := 'abcdefgh';
  BUCKET_NAME VARCHAR2(50) := 'analyticsContentTestBucket';
  l_content BLOB;
  l_content_clob CLOB;
  l_json_data JSON_OBJECT_T;
  compressed_clob CLOB;
  compressed_blob BLOB;
  uncompressed_blob BLOB;
  blob_length INT;
BEGIN

       DATASET_BLOB_DATA := UTIL.CLOB_TO_BLOB(TO_CLOB('There is BLOB data'));
       blob_length := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(DATASET_BLOB_DATA);     
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Length of compressed_blob: ' || blob_length);    
       DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_BLOB.PUT('CLIENT_ID',CLIENT_ID);-- := '{"CLIENT_ID": ' || CLIENT_ID || ', "BLOB_DATA": '||UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(DATASET_BLOB_DATA)||'}';
       DATASET_BLOB_DATA_CERNER_MONITORING :=  UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_COMPRESS(SRC => DATASET_BLOB_DATA);
        
        blob_length := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(DATASET_BLOB_DATA_CERNER_MONITORING);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Length of compressed_blob: ' || blob_length);
        DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_BLOB.PUT('BLOB_DATA', TO_CLOB(DATASET_BLOB_DATA_CERNER_MONITORING));
        
        DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_BLOB.PUT('BLOB_DATA', blob_to_clob(DATASET_BLOB_DATA_CERNER_MONITORING));
        
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_BLOB.TO_CLOB);
        DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_CLOB := DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_BLOB.TO_CLOB;
        DATASET_BLOB_DATA_CERNER_MONITORING := UTIL.CLOB_TO_BLOB(DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_CLOB);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DATASET_JSON_WITH_COMPRESSED_CLOB);
       OBJECT_STORAGE_URI_CERNER_MONITORING  := 'https://objectstorage.' || OCI_REGION || '.oraclecloud.com/n/' || OBJECT_STORAGE_NAMESPACE || '/b/' || BUCKET_NAME || '/o/' || 'blobdata123.json';
END;```

CLOB_TO_BLOB are written following the functions CONVERTTOCLOB and CONVERTTOBLOB respectively.
````

Comment: blob data is binary, whereas json is string. did you encode it base64 first before storing it as a string ? `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode([raw]))`. But that requires working with raw, not blob. You might want to read through the compressed blob in 2000 byte segments and populate an array of raw, which can then be base 64 encoded, cast to varchar2, and finally written to a destination CLOB which can be written to your json file. You'd need to reverse the process to get back to the original.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, I will try to implement what you have suggested.

Comment: What PaulW said... and interesting to note that you already have a `DATASET_BLOB_DATA_CERNER_MONITORING_BASE64_STR ` variable you aren't using, so it looks like that was the plan at some point. The immediate problem is that you convert the compressed BLOB to a CLOB, when it doesn't represent character data; and converting back later makes it worse. You can see that [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7pvUeh6J) - notice the length changes, ending up with 47 bytes for the compressed BLOB when you started with 38.